# Como pegar o valor de uma div e mostra no javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

> O metodo ".getElementById('valor').value" mostra o valor da div como null

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
<script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js" ></script>
<script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.tooltips.js" ></script>
<script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2", {uncompressed:true});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json.class.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../excanvas/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<p style="margin-left:50em;"><title>Cotação USD x BRL</title></p>

<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<meta name="Descrição" content="Cotação do Dolar de Acordo com o Real" />

</head>
<body>

<h2></h2>

<canvas id="cvs" width="900" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var data     = [document.getElementById('valor').value];
        var tooltips = [];
        //[2.59,2.60,2.40,2.67,1.78];

        // Create the tooltips
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=1) {
            tooltips[i] = '1 USD = ' + String(data[i] + ' Reais')
        }

        var line = new RGraph.Line({
            id: 'cvs',
            data: data,
            options: {
                tooltips: {
                    self: tooltips,
                    highlight: false
                },
                colors: ['#058DC7'],
                filled: true,
                fillstyle: 'rgba(229,243,249,0.5)',
                tickmarks: 'filledcircle',
                background: {
                    grid: {
                        vlines: false,
                        border: false,
                        autofit: {
                            numhlines: 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                shadow: false,
                linewidth: 3,
                gutter: {
                    left: 50,
                    right: 20
                },
                numxticks: 0,
                ylabels: {
                    count: 5
                },
                axis: {
                    color: '#aaa'
                },
                text: {
                    color: '#aaa'
                },
                labels: ['21/01','22/01','23/01','24/01','25/01']
            }
        })

        RGraph.ISOLD ? line.draw() : line.trace2();

    })
</script>

<div id="valor"></div>
<div id="label"></div>
```

Comment: de preferencia javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a propriedade value é referente a inputs e selects.

neste caso você precisa pegar o HTML interno da DIV.

```
.getElementById('valor').innerHTML
```

Comment: Ou, já que o código dele usa jQuery, `$('#valor').html()`.

Comment: eu já coloquei dos dois geitos sitados a cima, mais mesmo assim não mostra os valores

Comment: se for colocado os valores [2.59,2.60,2.40,2.67,1.78] direto na declaração do data aparece certinho mais não posso fazer assim, tenho que pegar da div   !!

Comment: @nardo_bruxo, essa div inicialmente não vem nada, como os valores são carregados? e aonde?

Comment: do arquivo json.class.js

Comment: poderia abrir a console e fazer um `console.log($('#valor').html());`?

Comment: Como se faz para passar um array da div para a variavel ??

Comment: O Html da div é uma string, neste caso você precisa fazer um JSON.parse. Então faça o seguinte JSON.parse($("#valor").val());

Comment: onde eu posso colocar o JSON.parse($("#valor").val()); ?